# LEFT JOIN not working to replace a NOT EXISTS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table called Documents and a table called Notes that stores notes for the Documents. I need to get all Documents where there are no notes that have a status of 2 or 3.

```
SELECT * FROM Documents 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT docID FROM Notes WHERE docId = id AND status IN (2, 3)
   )
```

This is extremely slow but it works. I tried doing an Inner join but if just one note has a status other than 2 or 3, it still shows the Document. I need it to only show Documents where there is no occurrence of 2 or 3 in any of the notes.

Can anyone help!? Thanks!

Comment: Your logic is inverted, should be: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT docID FROM Notes WHERE docId = id AND status IN (2, 3)
   )` Your plaintext: "*where there are no notes that have a status of 2 or 3.*"

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am trying to simplify a much more complicated query and I mistyped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **anti-join** is a familiar SQL pattern.

With that pattern, we use an outer join operation to return all rows, along with matching rows, *including* rows that don't have a match. The "trick" is to use a predicate in the WHERE clause to filter out all of the rows that found a match, leaving only rows that didn't have a match.

As an example, to retrieve rows from `Documents` that don't have any matching row in `Notes` that meet specified criteria:

```
SELECT d.* 
  FROM Documents d
  LEFT
  JOIN Notes n
    ON n.docId = d.id
   AND n.status IN (2,3)
 WHERE n.docId IS NULL
```

(I'm guessing that `docId` and `status` are references to columns in `Notes`, and that `id` is a reference to a column in `Documents`. The column references in your query aren't qualified, so that leaves us guessing which columns are in which table. Best practice is to qualify all column references in a query that references more than one table. One big benefit is that it makes it possible to decipher the statement without having to look at the table definitions, to figure out which columns are coming from which table.)

That query will return rows from `Documents` where there isn't any "matching" row in Notes that has a status of `2` or `3`.

Because the LEFT JOIN is an outer join, it returns *all* rows from `Documents`, along with matching rows from `Notes`. Any rows from `Documents` that don't have a matching row will be also be returned, with NULL values for the columns from `Notes`. The equality predicate in the join (`n.docId = d.Id`) guarantees us that any "matching" row will have a non-NULL value for `docId`.

The "trick" is the predicate in the `WHERE` clause:  `n.docId IS NULL`

Any rows that had a match will be filtered out, so we're left with rows from `Documents` that didn't have a match.

---

<strike>The original query has `status NOT IN (2,3)`. That would essentially ignore rows in `Notes` that have one of those statuses, and only a row with some other non-NULL value of status would "match". Based on the specification... "no notes with a status of 2 or 3", that seems to imply you'd want `status IN (2,3)` in the query.</strike>

Comment: EDIT: This works! But, it take 2 seconds to run through 10,000 rows. Any reason behind the time?

Comment: An `EXPLAIN` will show the execution plan (i.e. the operations that MySQL optimizer chooses.) Optimum performance is usually achieved simply by having suitable indexes available. Make sure you have an index with leading columns of `docId` and `status` on the `Notes` table, e.g. `ON Notes (docId,status)`. And if there isn't already an index with leading column of `id` on the `Documents` table, then `... ON Documents (id)`.

Comment: Problem solved! Missed an index on a column. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(docID)
FROM Documents
LEFT JOIN Notes ON docID = id AND (status IN (2,3))
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(docID) = 0
```

If there's a status=2 or status=3, then the count will be non-zero, and the `having` will eliminate the document entirely.